# MinGW MSYS ssh error: Could not create directory '/home/<username>/.ssh'

Tags: windows-7, ssh, mingw, msys

I have just installed a fresh MinGW installation on Windows 7 64bit using the Graphical User Interface Installer (the recommended approach) following the instructions given [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) and keeping the default options (i.e. installation in *C:\MinGW*) - hopefully without missing any steps or messing things up in any way.

However, when running the ***ssh*** command, I get the following error:

> C:\Users\myusername>ssh *username*@*host*
>   **Could not create directory '/home/*myusername*/.ssh'.**
>   The authenticity of host '*host* (*host-ip*)' can't be established.
>   RSA key fingerprint is *fingerprint*.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
>   **Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/*myusername*/.ssh/known_hosts).**

So, I basically have to confirm the connection every time.
Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error, I have found the solution(s) to the problem.

#### Automated solution (for the hasty)

1. Go to **(your-MinGW-installation-directory)\msys\1.0**.
   (in my case, which is also the default, that would be
   *C:\MinGW\msys\1.0*).
2. Run **msys.bat**.

This will start the *MinGW Shell*, which will create the path
***(your-MinGW-installation-directory)\msys\1.0\home\(your-username)***
automatically and *ssh* should now work just fine.

---

#### Manual solution (basically create the path required by hand):

1. Go to **(your-MinGW-installation-directory)\msys\1.0**.
2. Create a **home** directory.
3. Inside the **home** directory create a directory with the same name as your username.

So, now the path
***(your-MinGW-installation-directory)\msys\1.0\home\(your-username)***
is available and *ssh* should work just fine.

---

Here is what you should get if everything went well:

> C:\Users\myusername>ssh *username*@*host*
>   The authenticity of host '*host (host-ip)*' can't be established.
>   RSA key fingerprint is *fingerprint*.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
>   Warning: Permanently added '*host,host-ip*' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

**Note**
Since the MinGW Shell could create the path needed (without Windows UAC nagging about a thing), I guess this has nothing to do with persmissions. It is probably an omission of the MinGW installation.

Answer (score 1):

How to enable SSH in Windows to update my `known_hosts` file so that I am not always prompted

```
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts 
(/home/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts).
```

I spent all day trying to figure this out for git-bash for Windows (which I believe uses mingw64 which I believe is a descendant of msys).  I'm sure it is a permission error, but I could not find anything that states how to change the Unix permissions (i.e. chmod xxx ...) of a folder or file that is really controlled by Windows.  None of the following worked:

- Creating the `~/.ssh` folder in my Windows User's home directory (`cd ~ --> C:\User\username`)
- Creating the `/home/username/.ssh` folder in the git-bash root directory (`cd / --> C:\Program Files\Git`)
- Creating the `.ssh/known_hosts` file in both locations and changing the Windows permissions to Full Access

This worked:

- Changing the line in the file `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\nsswitch.conf`:

  ```
  From: db_home: env windows cygwin desc
    To: db_home:     windows cygwin desc
  ```

Why??? I have no idea!!

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This is an old, self-answered question.  You may have had a similar symptom, but there's no indication that the OP had included the env.  Might you have encountered the symptom simply because you created an error by including it?

Answer (score 0):

Manually add the rsa key to the .ssh/known_hosts file

Unsure why it's happening, my guess is permission issue if it can't even create the file in the first place

Comment: Thanks. However, I didn't really know where .ssh was supposed to be until I found my answer (which made adding the rsa key manually redundant).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using **`msys2`** and having the same error:

Change the the line in the file  `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to:

```
db_home: windows cygwin desc
```

[(From this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840871/ssh-is-looking-in-the-wrong-place-for-the-public-private-key-pair-on-windows/38878680#38878680)